# Generate a set of numbers based on some known value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numbers

Let's say I for a 6 digit values, with some known value, how do I generate all the possible set on numbers based on that? For example:

```
5 _ 8 _ _ _
```

So MATLAB will generates list of possible numbers:

```
5 9 8 1 2 5
5 4 8 4 5 1
.
.
.
```

without any same set of repetition number of course. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Sample code:

```
rand1=num2str(5);
rand2=num2str(randi([0 9],[1 1]));
rand3=num2str(8);
rand4=num2str(randi([0 9],[1 1]));
rand5=num2str(randi([0 9],[1 1]));
rand6=num2str(randi([0 9],[1 1]));

final=strcat(rand1,rand2,rand3,rand4,rand5,rand6)
```

Comment: I recommend showing what you have tried, and explicitly pointing out where it isn't working. Then we can help you with the specific issue. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry. Included! My code can't guarantee the generated number won't repeat, and if I were to put inside a loop(the codes), I don't know the definite numbers that is possible to generate.

Comment: You know that will be a long list right (10k elements)?

Comment: Do you want integers (the datatype) or strings? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'nchoosek' is what you are looking for. It takes a set of numbers and generates all combinations. Then 'unique' deletes possible repetitions.

```
%Input values
% Column 1: 1 if value already specified, 0 otherwise
% Column 2: Value for specified digits
input_matrix = [
       1 5;
       0 0;
       1 8;
       0 0;
       0 0;
       0 0;
    ];

    n_fixed = length(find(input_matrix(:,1))); %Elements already fixed
    n_total = size(input_matrix,1); %Total number of elements

    %Generate combinations (not repeated) for values not fixed
    comb = unique(nchoosek(repmat(0:9,1,9),n_total-n_fixed),'rows'); 
    n_combs = size(comb,1); %number of combinations

    %Insert known values
    for i=1:n_total
        if(input_matrix(i,1)) %value specified
                comb = [comb(:,1:i-1), input_matrix(i,2)*ones(n_combs,1), comb(:,i:end)];        
        end
    end
```

Comment: Never heard of `nchoosek` before. This is something new. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome! Thanks for accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
n = 10; % count
d = 6; % digits

res = cell(n,1);

for i = 1:n
    x = NaN(1,6);
    x(1) = 5;
    x(2) = randi([0 9],1,1);
    x(3) = 8;
    x(4:end) = randi([0 9],1,3);

    res{i} = strrep(num2str(x),' ','');
end
```